# AWS Forecast on Jupyter Notebook - Credentials error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-forecast

I'm following the [Quick Start Guide](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-forecast-samples/blob/main/notebooks/basic/Getting_Started/Amazon_Forecast_Quick_Start_Guide.ipynb) Jupyter Notebook from AWS in order to make AWS Forecast run with Python.

For the following cell, I replace :
[image: Notebook Cell 1]
adding my access informations to make it works :

```
session = boto3.Session(region_name=region, aws_access_key_id=access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)
```

However, I'm still stuck with the following cell :
[image: Where I don't pass]
where I don't know how to solve the current "NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials".

What should I add in the notebook to make it works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to make it work.

If you are on windows :

1. open powershell
2. run

   msiexec.exe /i https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi
3. restart powershell and run

   aws configure

Once completed, Jupyter notebook should work.